# Service Unavailable on Azure DevOps Local Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

First I installed Azure DevOps on windows server 2016 successfully then I could create Projects with Administrator user.After that I installed Active Directory. I don't know active directory is related with this problem or not.

---

Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

My steps to restart server:

1. Restarted Application Pool.
2. Restarted Team Project Collection.
3. Restarted Server

Team Project Collection:

[image: DevOps Team Project Collection Image]

Comment: Looks like more information is needed in your question on the steps you've taken etc. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer on your win server? That`s can be problem with service users after you have installed Active Directory.